# My table won't go to the next row?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a sample math worksheet with 10 questions. have a template which I have converted into a string which is to be output in my page 10 times (one for each question) once the user presses a 'Generate Question' button. The template consists of tables - one row for the question, another for the answer. It is meant to look like this :
[image]
*(Note that this is before I converted the table into a JavaScript string. It was pure HTML beforehand.)*

However, after making the template, I get an outcome like this even though I believe I've inserted  `<br>` correctly :
[image]

I've hit a brick wall here -- I can't seem to find a solution.

Here is my JS template code. The string is long, so keyword search "here is the break" to jump to where I want the break to be:

```
 // ---------- print template ----------
        var idQuestion =  "question" + i;
        var szQuestionHTML = '<td style="background-color: #66ff99;">' + i + '.' + '</td> <td style="background-color: #66ff99;" colspan="2" align="center"> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td id="qnom">' + qnom + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td id="qdenom" style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">' + qdenom + '</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> <td style="background-color: #66ff99;"> </td> </tr><br><!--here is the break that doesnt work--> <tr> <!--q1 options--> <td style="background-color: #cccccc;">a. <table> <tbody> <tr> <td id="a1">' + a1/*a1*/ + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td id="a2" style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">' + a2 + '</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> <td style="background-color: #cccccc;">b. <table> <tbody> <tr> <td id="b1">' + b1 + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td id="b2" style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">' + b2/*b2*/ + '</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> <td style="background-color: #cccccc;">c. <table> <tbody> <tr> <td id="c1">' + c1+ '</td> </tr> <tr> <td id="c2" style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">' + c2 + '</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> <td style="background-color: #cccccc;">d. <table> <tbody> <tr> <td id="d1">' + d1 + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td id="d2" style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">' + d2 + '</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td>';


        document.getElementById(idQuestion).innerHTML = szQuestionHTML;
// ---------- end print template ----------
```

Here is where the template is to be printed (assume that there are 10 of these, named question2, question3, etc. for each question respectively):
`<tr id="question1"><td></td></tr>`

I am not looking to solve this problem through jQuery or any other extensions/libraries as I would like to know the source of this problem instead. Unless, of course, it is impossible t fix which I highly doubt so. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT : I fixed the issue by separating the question string and answer string.**

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net showing what you tried?

Comment: If you examine the rendered html that is broken, you'll probably see your "break" is falling outside of an already closed `table` or `tr` or something else to throw it off.

Comment: @CaffGeek Here you go --  http://jsfiddle.net/xYLCD/1/ but the 'Generate Question' button doesn't work at all for some reason.

Comment: First thing:  I noticed a few instances of line breaks (`<br>`) between tables; you shouldn't do that; it's not really valid. Table rows (`<tr>`) are already on the next line down.

Comment: @ethorn10 Relocating `<br>` didn't work for me. I get the same outcome.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Table rows being on the next line down is exactly why I can't figure out why this is happening, which is what made me try to insert a line break in the first place. Removing said `<br>` rids the page of the white gap in between the two 'columns' (refer to the picture above) but doesn't get the question options row down to the next line.

Comment: @Xozzo - like @ChrisForrence said, get rid of the `<br>` and then when you generated your question and add the html via javascript, open up your developer tools (F12) and examine that block. You'll probably see that you've closed a `<table>` tag or something else that isn't valid html.